# How to get sObject from URL

Tags: sobject, id

How can I get the SObject from a url? Sample url:

> https://customcomp--dev.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/a044B000001koVmQAI/view?a:t=1490977419216

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the `SObjectType` of a given Id, you can just use a short `Execute Anonymous` script:

```
system.debug(Id.valueOf('<id_here>').getSObjectType());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Lightning, the standard approach is to use the [force:hasRecordId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_record_home.htm), as outlined in [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/building-context-aware-lightning-components.html). Basically, if you use this, your component will automatically have an attribute called recordId that you can use in your controller:

```
var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
```

Even better, implementing this interface allows you to "hint" places where the component can be used in the Lightning App Builder.